# How to get all selected values of a multiple select box?

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I have a `<select>` element with the `multiple` attribute. How can I get this element's selected values using JavaScript?

Here's what I'm trying:

```
function loopSelected() { 
    var txtSelectedValuesObj = document.getElementById('txtSelectedValues');
    var selectedArray = new Array();
    var selObj = document.getElementById('slct'); 
    var i;
    var count = 0;
    for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) { 
        if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
            selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
            count++; 
        } 
    } 
    txtSelectedValuesObj.value = selectedArray;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code written? With that would be easy to help :)

Comment: Most questions are outdated, here is the shortest path nowadays: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73949951

Answer (score 147, accepted):

No jQuery:

```
// Return an array of the selected opion values
// select is an HTML select element
function getSelectValues(select) {
  var result = [];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var opt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=options.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    opt = options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      result.push(opt.value || opt.text);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Quick example:

```
<select multiple>
  <option>opt 1 text
  <option value="opt 2 value">opt 2 text
</select>
<button onclick="
  var el = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
  alert(getSelectValues(el));
">Show selected values</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Could you please step through it for me? I think I understand MOST of it, but what does `var options = select && select.options;` do? In my **inexperience**, I expected that to be `var options = select.options;`

Comment: `select` is not the best variable name in JavaScript.

Comment: @TecBrat `var options = select && select.options` ensures that select is not undefined, before accessing its attributes.

Comment: I don't think the line with && makes much sense ... if `select`is not defined `getElementById`will return `null`. In this case, `options` will be null and error once you try to access to length property. But maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 134):

With jQuery, the usual way:

```
var values = $('#select-meal-type').val();
```

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> In the case of `<select multiple="multiple">` elements, the `.val()` method returns an array containing each selected option;

Comment: This is perfect. Is there also a way to retrieve the labels or text instead of the values themselves?

Answer (score 79):

Actually, I found the best, most-succinct, fastest, and most-compatible way using pure JavaScript (assuming you don't need to fully support IE lte 8) is the following:

```
var values = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#select-meal-type option:checked'),0).map(function(v,i,a) { 
    return v.value; 
});
```

**UPDATE (2017-02-14):**

An even more succinct way using ES6/ES2015 (for the browsers that support it):

```
const selected = document.querySelectorAll('#select-meal-type option:checked');
const values = Array.from(selected).map(el => el.value);
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you have the element: ```Array.from(element.querySelectorAll("option:checked"),e=>e.value);```

Comment: Just FYI, it is faster to use the selectedOptions/options collection than to use querySelectorAll.

Comment: Thanks @AdamLeggett. For reference to those who don't know, that would change make @Someguynamedpie's code above to: `Array.from(element.selectedOptions).map(v=>v.value);`.

Comment: It would, but see my answer below - it doesn't work at all on IE and has odd behavior in some older versions of Chrome and Firefox. If you don't care about performance, querySelectorAll or filtering element.options does get the job done. Also, you can do [].map.call() instead of using Array.from(), I don't know what impact this would have on performance but it certainly wouldn't be negative.

Comment: used `checked` 
This worked for me, on a multi select dropdown, but should work for all drop-downs as well
`$(".multiple_select > option:checked").each(function(){ 
    console.log(this.value) 
});`

Comment: This works in IE11: `var values = Array.prototype.slice.call(select.querySelectorAll('option:checked')).map(function(option){return option.value})`

Answer (score 74):

You can use `selectedOptions` property

```js
var options = document.getElementById('select-meal-type').selectedOptions;
var values = Array.from(options).map(({ value }) => value);
console.log(values);
```

```html
<select id="select-meal-type" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Breakfast</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Lunch</option>
    <option value="3">Dinner</option>
    <option value="4" selected>Snacks</option>
    <option value="5">Dessert</option>
</select>
```

Comment: A native, no-fuss, non-jQuery answer. Thank you.

Comment: this is a fantastic answer super simple and concise and can even be reduced to a single line `let selectedOptions = Array.from(document.getElementById(selectElem).selectedOptions).map(({ value }) => value);`

Comment: this works if the selected is in the options tag but did not work if changes on the form

Comment: In 2023 this should be the accepted answer. Much cleaner and cross-compatible. Does not require jQuery or other convoluted steps.

Comment: Thank you. `.selectedOptions` was not mentioned in the [`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) docs but is in [`HTMLSelectElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions)

Answer (score 45):

**ES6**

```
[...select.options].filter(option => option.selected).map(option => option.value)
```

Where `select` is a reference to the `<select>` element.

To break it down:

- `[...select.options]` takes the Array-like list of options and destructures it so that we can use Array.prototype methods on it (Edit: also consider using `Array.from()`)
- `filter(...)` reduces the options to only the ones that are selected
- `map(...)` converts the raw `<option>` elements into their respective values

Comment: Nice functional implementation :)

Comment: You could use just reduce() method
[My implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44574936/4725218)

Comment: If you can get reference to <select>, why not skip filter() step and just get reference to :checked children of <select> using querySelectorAll?

Comment: @Evgeny many ways to solve it. You should post your approach in a new answer.

Comment: This code looks much nicer than the ugly for loop over `options.length`. But is `[...select.options]` efficient in modern JS? Doesn't this iterate over whole collection three times? (i.e. first to build an array from options, second to filter, third to map) where you could do it in one go with ugly for loop

Comment: @Anentropic it's a good question but I don't think efficiency matters much unless we're talking about hundreds or thousands of options.

Answer (score 42):

If you wanna go the modern way, you can do this:

```
const selectedOpts = [...field.options].filter(x => x.selected);
```

The `...` operator maps iterable (`HTMLOptionsCollection`) to the array.

If you're just interested in the values, you can add a `map()` call:

```
const selectedValues = [...field.options]
                     .filter(x => x.selected)
                     .map(x => x.value);
```

Answer (score 28):

**Check-it Out:**

**HTML:**

```
<a id="aSelect" href="#">Select</a>
<br />
<asp:ListBox ID="lstSelect" runat="server"  SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100px">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Raj" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Karan" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Riya" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Aman" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Tom" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$("#aSelect").click(function(){
    var selectedValues = [];    
    $("#lstSelect :selected").each(function(){
        selectedValues.push($(this).val()); 
    });
    alert(selectedValues);
    return false;
});
```

**[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/unuta5)**

Comment: Not a fan - the "HTML" isn't HTML (readable, but not HTML), and the answer requires adding JQuery as a dependency.

Answer (score 18):

First, use `Array.from` to convert the `HTMLCollection` object to an array.

```
let selectElement = document.getElementById('categorySelect')
let selectedValues = Array.from(selectElement.selectedOptions)
        .map(option => option.value) // make sure you know what '.map' does

// you could also do: selectElement.options
```

Comment: Best answer for pure-javascript on modern browsers. +1

Answer (score 12):

suppose the multiSelect is the Multiple-Select-Element, just use its selectedOptions Property:

```
//show all selected options in the console:

for ( var i = 0; i < multiSelect.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
  console.log( multiSelect.selectedOptions[i].value);
}
```

Comment: Instead of just posting code, increase details about the way the code works.

Comment: Please don't put snippet just for JS, it's pointless without HTML and only give errors

Comment: @ShadowWizard got it

Comment: Note that `selectedOptions` is not supported in IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 11):

`$('#select-meal-type :selected')` will contain an array of all of the selected items.

```
$('#select-meal-type option:selected').each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

​

Answer (score 10):

Pretty much the same as already suggested but a bit different. About as much code as jQuery in [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/):

```
selected = Array.prototype.filter.apply(
  select.options, [
    function(o) {
      return o.selected;
    }
  ]
);
```

It [seems to be faster](http://jsperf.com/pick-selected-options-of-multiple-select) than a loop in IE, FF and Safari. I find it interesting that it's slower in Chrome and Opera.

Another approach would be using selectors:

```
selected = Array.prototype.map.apply(
    select.querySelectorAll('option[selected="selected"]'),
    [function (o) { return o.value; }]
);
```

Comment: Isn't the functionality of the first one already in Javascript?

Comment: Ok, got it. But the first one can be shorter. Just `select.selectedOptions`.

Comment: That's a drawback of bare JS compared to using libraries. The selectedOptions property lacks in [reliable browser support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711767/is-selectedoptions-broken-or). Library like jQuery will hide that from you. A lot has changed since 2013 but a quick google shows that people still have issues with selectedOptions.

Comment: There's no need to use `apply`. Use `call` and you can avoid having to pass an array of arguments.

Answer (score 8):

**Update October 2019**

The following should work "stand-alone" on all modern browsers without any dependencies or transpilation.

```html
<!-- display a pop-up with the selected values from the <select> element -->

<script>
 const showSelectedOptions = options => alert(
   [...options].filter(o => o.selected).map(o => o.value)
 )
</script>

<select multiple onchange="showSelectedOptions(this.options)">
  <option value='1'>one</option>
  <option value='2'>two</option>
  <option value='3'>three</option>
  <option value='4'>four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you need to respond to changes, you can try this:

```
document.getElementById('select-meal-type').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    let values = [].slice.call(e.target.selectedOptions).map(a => a.value));
})
```

The `[].slice.call(e.target.selectedOptions)` is needed because `e.target.selectedOptions` returns a `HTMLCollection`, not an `Array`. That call converts it to `Array` so that we can then apply the `map` function, which extract the values.

Comment: Sadly this won't work everywhere, turns out IE11 does not have the field selectedOptions. The following does work however: `Array.prototype.slice.call(field.querySelectorAll(':checked'))`

Answer (score 7):

Check this:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="test" multiple>
<option value="red" selected>Red</option>
<option value="rock" selected>Rock</option>
<option value="sun">Sun</option>
</select>
```

Javascript one line code

```
Array.from(document.getElementById("test").options).filter(option => option.selected).map(option => option.value);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('#select-meal-type').change(function(){
    var arr = $(this).val()
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#select-meal-type').change(function(){
  var arr = $(this).val();
  console.log(arr)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-meal-type" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="1">Breakfast</option>
  <option value="2">Lunch</option>
  <option value="3">Dinner</option>
  <option value="4">Snacks</option>
  <option value="5">Dessert</option>
</select>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTxfm/)

Answer (score 4):

if you want as you expressed with breaks after each value;

```
$('#select-meal-type').change(function(){
    var meals = $(this).val();
    var selectedmeals = meals.join(", "); // there is a break after comma

    alert (selectedmeals); // just for testing what will be printed
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an **ES6** implementation:

```
value = Array(...el.options).reduce((acc, option) => {
  if (option.selected === true) {
    acc.push(option.value);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: This works great. It's interesting to note that because `element.options` is a live collection, it cannot be reduced. It must first be converted to an Array as seen in the above answer.

Answer (score 4):

Building on [Rick Viscomi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39363742/8807809)'s answer, try using the HTML Select Element's [selectedOptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedOptions) property:

```js
let txtSelectedValuesObj = document.getElementById('txtSelectedValues');
[...txtSelectedValuesObj.selectedOptions].map(option => option.value);
```

In detail,

- `selectedOptions` returns a list of selected items.
- Specifically, it returns a read-only [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) containing [HTMLOptionElements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement).
- `...` is [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It expands the `HTMLCollection`'s elements.
- `[...]` creates a mutable `Array` object from these elements, giving you an array of `HTMLOptionElements`.
- `map()` replaces each `HTMLObjectElement` in the array (here called `option`) with its [value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement#Properties) (`option.value`).

Dense, but it seems to work.

Watch out, `selectedOptions` [isn't supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Browser_compatibility) by IE!

Answer (score 4):

Something like the following would be my choice:

```
let selectElement = document.getElementById('categorySelect');
let selectedOptions = selectElement.selectedOptions || [].filter.call(selectedElement.options, option => option.selected);
let selectedValues = [].map.call(selectedOptions, option => option.value);
```

It's short, it's fast on modern browsers, and we don't care whether it's fast or not on 1% market share browsers.

Note, selectedOptions has wonky behavior on some browsers from around 5 years ago, so a user agent sniff isn't totally out of line here.

Answer (score 3):

You can get as an array the values from the `<select>` at the submit of the form as this example :

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form-upload');

form.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const selectValue = formData.getAll('pets');
    console.log(selectValue);
})
```

```html
<form id="form-upload">
  <select name="pets" multiple id="pet-select">
      <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
      <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat</option>
      <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
      <option value="parrot">Parrot</option>
      <option value="spider">Spider</option>
      <option value="goldfish">Goldfish</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) is a [Web APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) facility, btw. It didn't first occur to me :)

Answer (score 2):

You Can try this script

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script>
    function getMultipleSelectedValue()
    {
      var x=document.getElementById("alpha");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
         if(x.options[i].selected ==true){
              alert(x.options[i].value);
          }
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="alpha">
      <option value="a">A</option>
      <option value="b">B</option>
      <option value="c">C</option>
      <option value="d">D</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="getMultipleSelectedValue()"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[].reduce` for a more compact implementation of [RobG's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5867262/1688034):

```
var getSelectedValues =  function(selectElement) {
  return [].reduce.call(selectElement.options, function(result, option) {
    if (option.selected) result.push(option.value);
    return result;
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: Array.prototype.filter would be a better option `[].filter.call(ele.options, e => e.selected)`

Answer (score 2):

My template helper looks like this:

```
 'submit #update': function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var obj_opts = event.target.tags.selectedOptions; //returns HTMLCollection
    var array_opts = Object.values(obj_opts);  //convert to array
    var stray = array_opts.map((o)=> o.text ); //to filter your bits: text, value or selected
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as the earlier answer but using underscore.js.

```
function getSelectValues(select) {
    return _.map(_.filter(select.options, function(opt) { 
        return opt.selected; }), function(opt) { 
            return opt.value || opt.text; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Works everywhere without jquery:

```
var getSelectValues = function (select) {
    var ret = [];

    // fast but not universally supported
    if (select.selectedOptions != undefined) {
        for (var i=0; i < select.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
            ret.push(select.selectedOptions[i].value);
        }

    // compatible, but can be painfully slow
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
            if (select.options[i].selected) {
                ret.push(select.options[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
};
```

Comment: `selectedOptiongs` is not supported in IE

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go.

```
const arr = Array.from(el.features.selectedOptions) //get array from selectedOptions property
const list = [] 
arr.forEach(item => list.push(item.value)) //push each item to empty array
console.log(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#application_student_groups option:selected').toArray().map(item => item.value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be great, if you could add a bit of explanation, how this is working and why you think, this is the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: 1) $('#application_student_groups option:selected') return collection of selected object
2) .toArray() return the selected objects in array
3) and in map I return the option value (or you can return text) from the array

we cannot judge a solution a best until we get a solution in the way we work. this is best solution for me as it works the way I work. hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own function like this and use it everywhere

**`Pure JS`**

```
/**
* Get values from multiple select input field
* @param {string} selectId - the HTML select id of the select field
**/
function getMultiSelectValues(selectId) {
 // get the options of select field which will be HTMLCollection
 // remember HtmlCollection and not an array. You can always enhance the code by
 // verifying if the provided select is valid or not
  var options = document.getElementById(selectId).options; 
    var values = [];
    
   // since options are HtmlCollection, we convert it into array to use map function on it
    Array.from(options).map(function(option) {
        option.selected ? values.push(option.value) : null
    })

    return values;
}
```

you can get the same result using jQuery in a single line

```
$('#select_field_id').val()
```

and this will return the array of values of well.