# Is selectedOptions broken or...?

Tags: javascript

Note: this question has nothing to do with Knockout.js, but it's about the `selectedOptions` attribute of `<select>` elements instead. This is the reference:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-button-element.html#dom-select-selectedoptions

I think it's a nice feature for Javascript developers. The support is quite limited, but it's growing anyway. Chrome, Opera and Safari should already support it.

The problem is that I can't figure out how it works. The behaviour should be quite straightforward, yielding a live collection of the selected options, but it turns out to be not the case. You'd imagine that `selectedOptions` changes everytime the user selects an option, right? Wrong. I've prepared a test case:

http://jsfiddle.net/f39cC/5/

In this example, Opera 11.64 **always** returns the first value selected, no matter what you do after, while Chrome 21 dev and 19 stable have an odd behaviour. Do the following steps:

1. Select 'One'. In both output and console you get "One", as expected.
2. Select 'Two' too, using Ctrl. In console you get "One,Two", in output it's still "One".
3. Select 'Three' too. In console it's "One,Two,Three", in output it's "One,Two".
4. Now select 'Two' only. In console you get "Two", in output "Two,," (notice the two commas).

**However**, if you comment out the `console.log` line, you always get the correct output. You can get the expected behaviour in both console and output if you swap the two instructions, or if you store the value in a separated string, as in this:

http://jsfiddle.net/f39cC/2/

So, am I missing something about `selectedOptions`? Is it too soon to rely on this property, that probably has a buggy implementation? Is `console.log` creating the issue in Chrome? Is there something I don't know about `HTMLCollection`s?

I don't have Safari installed, can someone check its behaviour?

**UPDATE 18/2/2013**: I don't know when things have changed, but both Chrome 24.0.1312.57 and Opera 12.14 seems to work fine now. Firefox 18.0.2 and Internet Explorer 10 still have to implement the property.

**UPDATE 17/9/2013**: Firefox 24 and IE 11 preview still have to support the property. This is an easy workaround for Firefox and IE8-11:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLSelectElement.prototype, "selectedOptions", {
    get: (function() {
        try {
            document.querySelector(":checked");
            return function() {
                return this.querySelectorAll(":checked");
            };
        } catch (e) {
            return function() {
                if (!this.multiple) {
                    return this.selectedIndex >= 0
                            ? [this.options[this.selectedIndex]] : [];
                }
                for (var i = 0, a = []; i < this.options.length; i++)
                    if (this.options[i].selected) a.push(this.options[i]);
                return a;
            };
        }
    })()
});
```

For IE8 it returns just an `Array` and not a `NodeList`, though.

**UPDATE 28/5/2014**: It looks like Firefox started implementing `selectedOptions` since r25.

Comment: From my research, yes it's broken, and [wasn't even implemented in firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596681). I could write it as answer, but you probably know all that by now...

Comment: Yes, I've read that bug page even before posting this question, but I was hoping that, since `selectedOption` *is* defined on `<select>` elements in Chrome and Opera, it could have an implementation that at least could *resemble* the specs. The fact that it's broken in *both* user agents caught me completely off guard, and I thought I was missing something, since it looks like a pretty simple feature. I've opened an issue in the Chromium project some days ago, thank you for confirming it.

Comment: I saw you even opened a ticket for chrome, so I didn't even "bother" answering... `:)` I'm sure your answer will be better than mine, You should do it.

Comment: Shim at https://gist.github.com/4212217

Comment: @BrettZamir It surely works, but that `Array.from` is ugly: a simple `[].slice.call(this.options)` will definitely be faster. But everything can be changed, since `filter` is slower than a `for` loop. Normally I'd also mind about the creation of an object of a user defined class, but these kind of collections are usually very small after all.

Comment: Good point re: Array.from, that was lifted by me from a library without much thought, now fixed, thanks. Using Array.prototype was about as fast in Firefox as [], but shorter is nicer. As far as filter, I'd assume that has the potential for being optimized by browsers where not already? I like to use functional intuitive style wherever possible... As far as user class, yeah, just trying to be faithful to API.

Comment: @BrettZamir Yeah, I'd like to use `filter`, `map` and all these functions as much as possibly too, but since they use a callback function they're quite slow, expecially when all you have to do is to check a property. Anyway, `selectedOptions` would hardly be a performance-critic property, so I guess it's alright here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the problem is a bit deeper than a simple bug. The fact that both WebKit and Presto failed to support `selectedOptions` correctly gives us the hint that it depends on the fact that the property is supposed to be a `HTMLCollection`.

Now, `HTMLCollection`s have their live behaviour because they're invalidated by the rendering engine when something happens to the DOM (the change of a class, the removal of a node and so on). But the `selected` property of an option **does not** trigger the invalidation of the collection, thus making it completely unreliable.

I guess the problem here is to make a new way live collections are invalidated, and it may be not very simple since it may affect the whole way the DOM is interpreted and handled.

At the present time, Chrome 21.0.1180.4 has the property removed.

Comment: [Supported browser list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13753605/465053) for `selectedOptions` attribute