# jQuery: find the <optgroup> for a selected value in a <select> element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I have a dropdown menu with different option groups. If someone selects an option, how can I check which optgroup it belongs to? For example if 'ferrari' were selected, how would you determine which optgroup it belongs to?

Feel free to use jQuery or raw javascript.

```
<select name="testSelect">
   <optgroup label="fruits">
      <option value="apples">Apples</option>
      <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
      <option value="pears">Pears</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="cars">
      <option value="ford">ford</option>
      <option value="toyota">toyota</option>
      <option value="ferrari">ferrari</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: Wait. This may be as trivial as finding the parent of the selected element.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can do this using jQuery:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selected = $(':selected', this);
    alert(selected.closest('optgroup').attr('label'));
});​
```

See a live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/zjLCp/1/

**Update:** Yes you could use `parent` http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/zjLCp/2/

```js
alert(selected.parent().attr('label'));
```

Comment: strange to see that .click event is not available in jquery for this element..!!

Answer (score 13):

Well, in pure js:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].parentNode.label
```

Not a single function call and less code to boot. :-)

Comment: this.selectedOptions[0].parentNode.label

Comment: @lokeshjain2008—I presume the OP wants a reliable method, not something [partially supported in a couple of browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711767/is-selectedoptions-broken-or).

Comment: No problem. Stuff in the [WHATWG spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/) tends to be a bit "out there", the [W3C HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html) is closer to what is actually available, but still a bit bleeding edge in places.

Comment: Can this be done in react given the onClick handler event?