# selectedOptions[0].textContent; not working in IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

```
function call(op) {
    var x = op.selectedOptions[0].textContent;
    var n = x.substring(0, 3);
    //alert(n);
    document.pts.inputbox.value = n;
    document.pts.submit();
}
```

I have a function that grabs the label value from a selected option in a list box, then it disects out the first 3 letters and passes that information on to an input box value.

The issue is with how the js is grabbing the selected options label text content. It seems to work in Chrome just fine, but in firefox17 and IE9 nothing happens. Any suggestions on a better way to get the selected options label value?

EDIT:
I can NOT use the options value, that value is reserved for something more specific
Everything works fine in JSfiddle.

Comment: Have you considered using value attributes in the `<option>`s and the value property of the select instead of the `<option>`s' text.

Comment: Can you try to put your code on http://jsfiddle.net site so that it will be easy for us to investigate ?

Comment: Yes, I cannot use the options Value, that number is for something else.

Comment: @ durgaprasad everything works fine in JSfiddle

Comment: `.selectedOptions...` what API is this? do you mean `HTMLSelectElement.selectedIndex` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10711767/is-selectedoptions-broken-or

Comment: @ scunliffe Yes but, I do not want to use the index. I Must use the label text. hence the .textContent -- The reason is because the the Label is created from an INI file using PHP. I want the user to be able to "Tag" the label in the ini file using the first 3 characters of the Label.

Comment: You may try this `element.options[element.selectedIndex].text`, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/fCnQE/).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this

```
function call(op) {
    var x = op.options[op.selectedIndex].text;
    var n = x.substring(0, 3);
    alert('Index : '+op.selectedIndex+' and first 3 lettrs are : '+n);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V7ehJ/1/).

Answer (score 14):

Based on a quick [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f39cC/29/), the `selectedOptions` collection isn't widely supported yet.

**Fails/Unsupported:**

- IE10 (Desktop or Metro)
- IE11
- Safari 7
- iOS6 Opera Mini
- Android 4.0.4 Browser
- Android 4.0.4 Firefox Browser

**Works:**

- Chrome 23.0.1271.95
- Opera 12.11
- BlackBerry 10 Browser
- iOS6 Safari
- iOS6 Chrome
- Android 4.0.4 Opera Mobile Browser
- Firefox 53.0
- Edge

Comment: for cross-browser support, https://caniuse.com/?search=selectedOptions is an excellent resource that'll update as more recent versions come out