# Split values by comma separated string in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my issue:

I have RadListBox and I'm trying to get the values and append them so the result would be displayed like that: '1,2,3,4' but I'm getting back : 1,2,3,4, 
Does anyone know how can I achieve that?

Problem starts here:

```
var sbLocationsIDS = new StringBuilder();
             for (i = 0; i < LocationIDS.get_items().get_count(); i++) {
                 sbLocationsIDS.append(LocationIDS.getItem(i).get_value()+ ",");  
             }
```

The result: sbLocationsIDS =1,2,3,4, instead of '1,2,3,4'

The Rest of the Code:

```
 function openNewTab(url) {
         var captureURL = url;
         var win = window.open(captureURL, '_blank');
         win.focus();
     }

     function GetComparisonsReport(sender, args) {
         var isValid = Page_ClientValidate('validateComparisons');
         if (isValid) { // If its true is going to fire the rest of the code
             var SessionID = getUrlVars()["SessionID"];
             var companyCodeVal = document.getElementById("<%=hfC.ClientID%>").value;
             var LocationIDS = $find("<%=rlbSelectedLocation.ClientID %>");
             var CategoriesIDS = $find("<%=rlbSelectedCategory.ClientID %>");
             var fileType = $find("<%=rcbFileType.ClientID %>");
             var fromFirstPeriod = $find("<%=rdpFromFirstPeriod.ClientID %>");
             var toFirstPeriod = $find("<%=rdpToFirstPeriod.ClientID %>");
             var fromSecondPeriod = $find("<%=rdpFromSecondPeriod.ClientID %>");
             var toSecondPeriod = $find("<%=rdpToSecondPeriod.ClientID %>");;
              if (LocationIDS.get_items().get_count() < 0) {
                 radalert("Please choose locations and select the Add button.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 420, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                 return;
             }
             if (CategoriesIDS.get_items().get_count() < 0) {
                 radalert("Please choose categories and select the Add button.<h3 style='color: #ff0000;'></h3>", 420, 170, "Case Global Alert");
                 return;
             }
             var fromFirstPeriodDateValSelected = fromFirstPeriod.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate().format("yyyy/MM/dd");
             var toFirstPeriodDateValSelected = toFirstPeriod.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate().format("yyyy/MM/dd");
             var fromSecondPeriodDateValSelected = fromSecondPeriod.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate().format("yyyy/MM/dd");
             var toSecondPeriodDateValSelected = toSecondPeriod.get_dateInput().get_selectedDate().format("yyyy/MM/dd");
             var fileTypeValSelected = fileType.get_selectedItem().get_value();


             var sbLocationsIDS = new StringBuilder();
             for (i = 0; i < LocationIDS.get_items().get_count(); i++) {
                 sbLocationsIDS.append(LocationIDS.getItem(i).get_value()+ ",");  // The problem is here!!!
             }
             var sbCategoriesIDS = new StringBuilder();
             for (i = 0; i < CategoriesIDS.get_items().get_count(); i++) {
                 sbCategoriesIDS.append(CategoriesIDS.getItem(i).get_value() + ",");
             }
             var ComparisonsURL = (String.format("https://www.test.com/cgis/{0}/reports/ConnectTorptIncidentsCountByLocationInterval.asp?SessionID={1}&locString={2}&catString={3}&FromDate1={4}&&ToDate1={5}&FromDate2={6}&ToDate2={7}&ExportType={8}", companyCodeVal, SessionID, sbLocationsIDS, sbCategoriesIDS, fromFirstPeriodDateValSelected, toFirstPeriodDateValSelected, fromSecondPeriodDateValSelected, toSecondPeriodDateValSelected, fileTypeValSelected));
             openNewTab(ComparisonsURL);
         }
     }

     String.format = function () {
         // The string containing the format items (e.g. "{0}")
         // will and always has to be the first argument.
         var theString = arguments[0];
         // start with the second argument (i = 1)
         for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
             // "gm" = RegEx options for Global search (more than one instance)
             // and for Multiline search
             var regEx = new RegExp("\\{" + (i - 1) + "\\}", "gm");
             theString = theString.replace(regEx, arguments[i]);
         }
         return theString;
     }

     function getUrlVars() {
         var vars = {};
         var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function (m, key, value) {
             vars[key] = value;
         });
         return vars;
     }

     // Initializes a new instance of the StringBuilder class
     // and appends the given value if supplied
     function StringBuilder(value) {
         this.strings = new Array("");
         this.append(value);
     }

     // Appends the given value to the end of this instance.
     StringBuilder.prototype.append = function (value) {
         if (value) {
             this.strings.push(value);
         }
     }

     // Clears the string buffer
     StringBuilder.prototype.clear = function () {
         this.strings.length = 1;
     }

     // Converts this instance to a String.
     StringBuilder.prototype.toString = function () {
         return this.strings.join("");
     }
```

Comment: Can't you just remove the last character of a string with .slice(0,-1)? Or am i oversimplifying?

Comment: No it's throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your loop is appending `,` always even for the last item in the loop.

You want to append only for all items other than the last. There are multiple ways to do that, simplest being: check if the current element is the last and if so, do not append `,`

```
    var sbLocationsIDS = new StringBuilder();
    for (i = 0; i < LocationIDS.get_items().get_count(); i++) {
        sbLocationsIDS.append(LocationIDS.getItem(i).get_value()); //append only value
        if(i != (LocationIDS.get_items().get_count() -1)) { //if not last item in list
            sbLocationsIDS.append(","); //append ,
        }
    }
```

There are other ways to do it, and depending on what you want to do with the values in the future, these may be pretty useful. (I see that the `append` in your code is actually a call to `join`, so this is actually a simpler version)

Add the values of the list to a array and use [`Array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var select = document.getElementById("locationId");
var options = select.options;
var optionsArray = [];
if(options) {
    for (var i=0; i<=options.length; i++) {
        //text is the text displayed in the dropdown. 
        //You can also use value which is from the value attribute of >option>
        optionsArray.push(options[i].text);  
    }
}
var sbLocationsIDS = optionsArray.join(",");
```

With JQuery, the above code becomes a bit more simple:

```
var optionsArray = [];
$("#locationId option").each(function(){
    optionsArray.push(options[i].text);
});
var sbLocationsIDS = optionsArray.join(",");
```

Actually, if you decide yo use JQuery, you can use [`jquery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):
(idea from [Assigning select list values to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163732/assigning-select-list-values-to-array#answer-16163894))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#b").click(function() {
    var sbLocationsIDS = jQuery.map($("#locationId option"), function(n, i) {
      return (n.value);
    }).join(",");
    alert(sbLocationsIDS);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="locationId">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button id="b">Click</button>
```

Comment: How can I warp it with single quotes like '1,2,3,4'