# How can I send multiple select choices through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I am submitting a form through ajax. Currently, I put together the post data like this:

```
for(i=0; i<document.formname.elements.length; i++){
  if(document.formname.elements[i].type=='checkbox' && document.formname.elements[i].checked!=true){continue;}
  if (i>0){data = data + "&";}
  data = data + document.formname.elements[i].name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(document.formname.elements[i].value);
}
```

This worked until I changed one of my select boxes to select multiple. This code snippet only gets the one of the selected values.

imagine I have this in my form:

```
<select name="selectme[]" multiple>
  <option value="">Select Something</option>
  <option value="987987">Choice 1</option>
  <option value="35987">Another Choice</option>
  <option value="98987">Choice 3</option>
</select>
```

How would I detect and gather the additional selections?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting all selected values of a multiple select box when clicking on a button using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/getting-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box-when-clicking-on-a-button-u)

Comment: Yes, I flagged my own question. :)

Comment: glad I took the time to answer it then :/

Comment: @pennstatephil I appreciate your effort, but I was looking for the vanilla version. I kept digging and finally found a working function as an answer to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using jquery's [Serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on the form.

if you want to go through manually, look for the "selected" attribute on each option.