# Not getting multiple values while i am selecting values from drop down in jquery this.value

Tags: php, jquery

Here is my code i am struggling with the multiple values select with jquery if i will select two values i should get two values in the function test

```
<html>
<select name="hello[]" id="hello" multiple="multiple" onchange="test(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Value</option>
<option value="1">PHP</option>
<option value="2">JAVA</option>
<option value="3">.NET</option>
<option value="4">ORACLE</option>
<option value="5">DBA</option>
</select>
</html>
<script>
function test(xx)
{

alert(xx);
}
```

please help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/getting-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box-when-clicking-on-a-button-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code similar to your approach

```
<script>
var hello = new Array(); 
function test(xx)
{
  hello.push(xx);
  alert(hello);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Every time it is pushing only one value i.e same value

Comment: yes when you need value just explode it and do array_unique so that you can get unique items

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this:

```
onchange="test(this.value);"
```

and jQuery:

```
var test = function(x) {
   alert(x);
}

$(document).on('change', '#hello', function() {
       var val = $(this).val();
       test(val);
});
```

or more compact:

```
$(document).on('change', '#hello', function() {
       var val = $(this).val();
       alert(val);
});
```

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/bwrwd25e/)