# Html select multiple get all values at onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, select, onchange, multi-select

I have a form with a select multiple. I want to get all selected values at onchange event but i dont know if this is possible. I think "this.value" only returns the last element selected.

Is it possible to get all the elements selected as array at onchange??

Thanks in advance.

```
<select name="myarray[]" id="myarray" class="select2-select req" style="width: 90%;" onChange="get_values(this.value)" multiple>
    {foreach key=key item=value from=$myarray}
         <option value="{$key}" >{$value}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

Comment: are you using jQuery? or just plain javascript

Comment: You can have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/getting-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box-when-clicking-on-a-button-u

Comment: It’s possible to use `myarray.selectedOptions`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all selected values of a multiple select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This example might help without jQuery:

```js
function getSelectedOptions(sel) {
  var opts = [],
    opt;
  var len = sel.options.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    opt = sel.options[i];

    if (opt.selected) {
      opts.push(opt);
      alert(opt.value);
    }
  }

  return opts;
}
```

```html
<select name="myarray[]" id="myarray" class="select2-select req" style="width: 90%;" onChange="getSelectedOptions(this)" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use jquery to solve it:

```
get_values=function(){
    var retval = [];    
    $("#myarray:selected").each(function(){
        retval .push($(this).val()); 
    });
    return retval;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example below, i'm builiding arrays of selected options and selected values :

```
<select id="my-array" multiple>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

```
const myArray = document.getElementById('my-array');
myArray.addEventListener('change', (e) => {

  const options = e.target.options;
  const selectedOptions = [];
  const selectedValues = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i].selected) {
      selectedOptions.push(options[i]);
      selectedValues.push(options[i].value);
    }
  }

  console.log(selectedOptions);
  console.log(selectedValues);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An ES6 answer:

```
let options: HTMLOptionElement[] = Array.from(event.target.options);

let selected = options
.filter(o => o.selected)
.map(o => o.value);
```