# How to get the values from <select multpile={true}> in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, controlled-component

I have a form that has a select-multiple field. It is just getting one value that is first clicked but not the other values that are clicked after clicking the first one. Hhow to get the values? Below is my code.

assignment of state, Here shift and board are the state to store the values of multi-select field

```
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    name: "",
    photo: "",
    adhar: "",
    phone: "",
    location: "",
    fullAddress: "",
    age: "",
    gender: 0,
    schooName: "",
    experience: "",
    teachForNoDays: "",
    shift: [],
    subject: "",
    teachClass: "",
    board: [],
    homeTuition: false,
    fees: "",
    homeTuitionFees: "",
  });
```

onChange function

```
const changeFormData = (e) => {
    // this is how we do when to specifically define a type in the target
    const { name, type } = e.target;
    console.log(e.target.value);
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: e.target[type === "checkbox" ? "checked" : "value"],
    });
  };
```

the fields, only putting up the shift one here

```
<select
   name="shift"
   id="shift"
   defaultValue={shift}
   size={2}
  onChange={(e) => changeFormData(e)}
   multiple={true}
  >
     <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
     <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<select>` has an `e.target.options` field which is an array containing all the selected options.

You should take that into consideration in `changeFormData()`.

Don't forget to properly "**control**" the value of your select component by assigning it with the current value:

```
<select
   ...
   value={formData.shift}
   multiple
  >
     ...
</select>
```

Comment: Check out this question for better clarification: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30372235/html-select-multiple-get-all-values-at-onchange-event

Comment: So how do you use this to store the array of options in suppose shift, can you please post an  ans using that

Comment: Should look like this `[name]: type === "select" ? [...e.target.options.map(o => o.value)] : e.target[type === "checkbox" ? "checked" : "value"]`

Comment: No, it did not work after form submission the shift only stores the first option that was cliked not the array

Comment: Please paste the current code being run in the original question for me to properly help