# Sending a list of checkboxes via Ajax to Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have a list of checkboxes in a table in my Django app. The user selects some of them and then clicks an action button. A small popup modal form then pops up, where they fill in info related to the selected items and they can also upload a file in the in the popup. I need to send the selected checkboxes' ids and the form fields in the modal to Django via ajax

I've wrapped the modal in a form tag and that all works well. I'm struggling sending the list of selected IDs to Django. When the user selects id 31 and 32, it sends it as '31,32' as a string and Django can't decode it. I'm sure it is a quick fix, but my javascript knowledge is limited.

Below is my code:

Html:

```
<tr>
    <td ><input class="selection-box" type="checkbox" name="action" value="{{ item.id }}"></td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ><input class="selection-box" type="checkbox" name="action" value="{{ item.id }}"></td>
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
submitHandler: function () {
    var matches = [];
    $(".selection-box:checked").each(function() {
        matches.push(this.value);
    });
    var form = document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo");// This is the popup form that contains that file upload box and other fields
    var oData = new FormData(form);
    if (matches.length) {
        oData.append('action', matches);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'post',
        data: oData,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success == true) {
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Django view:

```
# This generates the error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '33,31'  
selected_list = self.request.POST.getlist('action')
```

Comment: print selected_list  ??

Comment: I can't print it because it generates the ValueError

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5867262/3762142 helps...

Comment: use `name="action[0]"`for first checkbox and `name="action[1]"` for second check box that will convert it into array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are manually doing the 'decoding', instead of using `.getlist`, you can go with `.get` and `.split`:

```
selected_list = self.request.POST.get('action', '').split(',')
```

but have in mind that the returned `list` will contain your `ids` as strings, so you can use `map` to convert them to integers.

```
try:
    cleaned_list = map(int, selected_list)
except ValueError:
    #list is empty: ['']
    cleaned_list = []
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this will do the trick, but isn't there a better way to achieve this? Other places in the app I just send 'action=31&action=32' then request.POST.getlist('action') returns ['31','32']

Comment: Im not sure if its going to work, but in the JS try instead of `oData.append('action', matches);` to append one element at a time: `matches.forEach(function(match) { oData.append('action', match) });`

Comment: Yes, that worked! Now, the only thing I'm not sure of, when using a query in Django such as MyModel.objects.filter(pk__in=my_list), does 'my_list" have to be integers?

Comment: You will get a `ValueError` if some of the values can't be casted to `int`.