# Get two values from select option at once

Tags: javascript, php

How can I have to values at once from select options through JavaScript function?

Here is my code:

```
<select name="ledger" id="ledger" onchange="setDebit(this.value)" required>
    <option value="" >Select</option>
    <?php
        $ledgerResult = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM ledger WHERE account_type = "Creditors" ORDER BY name');
        $ledgerData = $ledgerResult->result();

        for ($c = 0; $c < count($ledgerData); ++$c) {
                    $ledger_id = $ledgerData[$c]->id;
                    $ledger_name = $ledgerData[$c]->name;
                    $ledger_credit = $ledgerData[$c]->credit; ?>

        <option value="<?php echo $ledger_id;?>"><?php echo $ledger_name;?></option>
        }
</select>

<script>
    function setDebit(ele){
        document.getElementById("set_debit").value = ele;
    }
</script>
```

I am getting `$ledger_id` and sending this value through `setDebit()` to the script. But what I need is to send `$ledger_credit`. I can do it by setting it as  option value instead of `$ledger_id;` but I also need value of `select`as `$ledger_id`.

How can I set $ledger_id as option value, but send $ledger_credit through `setDebit(this.value)`?

Comment: what did you mean by "get two values"? You want to select *mutiple*?

Comment: CONCAT both $ledger_id.":".$ledger_credit in the option value, then split it with javascript, e.g. var.split(":")

Comment: No, I need to set option value as $ledger_id, which I have done. But at the same time I need to send $ledger_credit through setDebit() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using jquery.

```
<option value="<?php echo $ledger_id."||".$ledger_credit; ?><?php echo $ledger_name;?> </option>
```

> ```
>  <script>
>    function setDebit(){
>      var details = document.getElementById("ledger").value;
>      var allData = details.split("||");
>      var ledger_id = allData[0];
>      var ledger_credit = allData[1];
>      console.log(ledger_id);
>      console.log(ledger_credit);
> }
> </script>
> ```

Comment: Its not working. details variable is not getting the expected value from ledger.

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: No. I m using straight javascript.

Comment: ok now check and no need to pass parameter in onchange function. just use onchange="setDebit()"

Comment: Thank u so much. Ur solution helped me a tons, dude. But one more thing which I m not clear about.

Comment: Setting option value like this: <?php echo $ledger_id."||".$ledger_credit ?> means I m setting two values which I will split later. But, which value I m passing through though ledger to database? $ledger_id or $ledger_credit? I can see the 1st one. Why its passing only the 1st one rather than both or the 2nd one?

Comment: you can pass ether ledger_id or ledger_credit. its depends on you which value you are going to send. can you show me how you are sending values

Comment: I just catching the value like this:
$ledger_id = $this->input->post('ledger');

Comment: ok then in php code also you can split and take the values. as you done in your javascript function

Comment: Oh got it. Thank you again so much dude.

Comment: @Saud you are most welcome. can you please upvote this answer if working

Comment: I tried from the very beginning dude. Its restricted. I hope you appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <option value="<?php echo $ledger_id.":".$ledger_credit;?>"><?php echo $ledger_name;?></option>

    function setDebit(ele){
            var Value = document.getElementById("ledger").val();
            var Parts = Value.split(":");
            var LedgerID = Parts[0];
            var LedgerCredit = Parts[1];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the attribute multiple in the HTML part:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

After that you can have a look at this question for further info:
[How to get all selected values of a multiple select box using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/getting-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box-when-clicking-on-a-button-u)

Comment: No you didn't get the point. I will select an option, i.e., $ledger_name. And then, option value will be set as $ledger_id, and setDebit(this.value) function value will be set as $ledger_credit.

Comment: Oh I understand, maybe you should think about just sending the ID and converting it back to the credit on the server side(using an associative array or database query in the PHP code), things on the client side can easily be spoofed

Answer (score 0):

You can add an atribute `data-credit` in yours options

```
<option value="<?php echo $ledger_id;?>" data-credit="<?php echo $ledger_credit;?>"><?php echo $ledger_name;?></option>
```

And in the `setDebit` function:

```
var ledger_credit = $('option:selected', "#ledger").data('credit');
```

You must use jquery in this solution