# i always get the last selected value in hidden field

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to pass the selected value into a hidden field but I always get the last value of option.

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('section');?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <select name="section_id" class="form-control selectboxit" style="width:100%;">
            <?php
                foreach($sections as $row):
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['section_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
     <input type="text" name="section_id" value="<?php echo $row['section_id']?>">



<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('subject');?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="subject_id" class="form-control selectboxit" style="width:100%;">
        <?php
            $subjects = $this->db->get_where('enroll' , array('section_id' => $section_id))->result_array();
            foreach($subjects as $row):
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to pass the hidden field value to  query inside the  second dropdown how to do this

Comment: where you are sending this values?

Comment: Post details about your requirements.

Comment: i want to send this value to query within another selectbox down there 

    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <select name="subject_id" class="form-control selectboxit" style="width:100%;">
        <?php
         $subjects = $this->db->get_where('enroll' , array('section_id' => $section_id))->result_array();
         foreach($subjects as $row):
        ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['student_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
     <?php endforeach;?>
        </select>
    </div>

Comment: @sud send that id to any function onchange event. then you can take that value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260223/get-two-values-from-select-option-at-once/41260621#41260621

Comment: yes but how to send that value to the query inside?

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly pass section_id value to a text field, because it will always give last section_id. You should use below jquery to assign selected option value to text field:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectboxit').on('change', function() {
        $('#section_id').val(this.value);
    })
});
```

Comment: i gave the this to an alert  alert("section"+$('#section_id').val(this.value)); it gives me [object Object] any reason?

Comment: try to print this value into your console tab in your browser. and fetch required value:

    console.log(this.value);

Comment: ok when it gives like console.log(this.value): it prints the expected values..now is that possible to assign this value to php varaible?

Comment: Since PHP is a Server side language and JavaScript is client side. So directly you can not assign js value to php variable. Either you need to pass this value as query parameter or via Ajax.

Comment: i tried to give like this an getting neither display anything nor error 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.selectboxit1').on('change', function() {
       
         var val=(this.value);

        alert("val"+val);
   


        $.ajax({
            alert(
             url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/get_class_section_by_section/' + val ,
            success: function(response)
            
          
             {
                 //jQuery('#section_subject_selection_holder').html(response);
             }
        });
        })
    });

Comment: @sud, Use this code and try to fix your issue:


    `$(document).ready(function () { 
 $('.selectboxit1').on('change', function() { 
            var val=(this.value); 
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/get_class_section_by_section/'+val,
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#section_subject_selection_holder').html(response)‌​; 
                }
            }); 
 }); 
    });`