# how select multiple value property is handled by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

In jQuery if you have select multiple with two values if I use:

```
$('select').val()
```

I've got:

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

but in javascript/native DOM:

```
$('select')[0].value
```

I've got:

```
"foo"
```

why I've got just the first value and not an array? How to get the same value as in jQuery? I don't see anything special in [jQuery source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.12-stable/src/attributes/val.js) that check if select have attribute multiple.

Here is demo:

```js
console.log($('select').val());
console.log($('select')[0].value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple>
  <option value="foo" selected>foo</option>
  <option value="bar" selected>bar</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If you're looking for a way to get all values without using jQuery you can check all options for the "selected" attribute. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box-using-javascript)

Comment: ... Why? If you're still using jQuery to get the `select`, why do you want to use `'value'?

Comment: jQuery `val` function is "special", because it loops though array