# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. on document.execCommand("copy"); for a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, clipboard, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet that takes field names and copies them to my clipboard. 
I am getting the error back Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

```
    function copy() {
  var number = document.getElementById('sys_readonly.rm_story.number').value,
      shortDescription = document.getElementById('rm_story.short_description').value,
      d = new Date(),
      year = d.getFullYear(),
      month = d.getMonth(),
      day = d.getDate(),

      name = year + month + day + ' - ' + number + ' - ' + shortDescription;

  name.select(),
  document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `;` instead of `,` at the end of lines

Comment: I did it like that so I wouldn't have to write `var` multiple times.

Comment: name.select(), ends with a `,`

Comment: That should be a `;` instead of `,`

Comment: I see what you're saying now. That was a miss, thank you. But that still does not work. It is not copying to my clipboard

Answer (score 0):

Following up on your last comment
Possible duplicate, your problem is discussed in: [JavaScript execCommand('copy') not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45117731/javascript-execcommandcopy-not-working)