# JS check if there is a value is selected in select multiple

Tags: javascript, html

When I want to check if an input field has a value I can use

```
document.getElementById('datum').value == false
```

But how to check if there is a value selected in a multiple select?

```
<select multiple id="letsel_soort[]" name="letsel_soort[]" multiple="multiple" onkeyup="validate()" onmousemove="validate()">
```

Comment: If you use jquery you could use $("select[name='letsel_soort[]'] option:selected").length;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all selected values of a multiple select box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box)

Comment: @terry, no duplicate. I just need to check if there are any selected before the form is submitted.

Comment: You can repurpose that logic to check the number of selected values. >1? Means any is selected. === 0? Means none is selected.