# ReactJs How to handle event handler only after multiple selection of dropdown?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code with multiple select dropdown list. The handle change calls on selecting each value from the dropdown. How can i change this to call the handleChange function only after selecting the multiple values?

```
handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}

render() {

    return(
        <select className="form-control" key="1" name="degree" onChange={this.handleChange} multiple>
            <option value="1" key="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" key="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" key="3">3</option>
            <option value="4" key="4">4</option>
            <option value="5" key="5">5</option>
        </select>
        )
}
```

Update:
I need to get the array of selected values in the console is my basic requirement.

Comment: how do you know when the required value is selected, as apposed to any other value in the list?

Comment: I mean after selecting multiple values. Any event handlers there for doing this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'selecting the multiple values' in a dropdown?

Comment: So the condition is `selectedValues > 1`?

Comment: I believe you are looking for  -> `e.target.selectedOptions` not a value

Comment: @shaedrich, @The Reason, I was trying to get array of selected values in console. I tried with `e.target.selectedValues` but gives undefined.

Comment: It seems that js doesn't offer such a property although I think, it would be pretty good to have one. Then maybe some of these solutions might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box

Comment: It actually has something like this. If you do not care about IE, you could use the `selectedOptions` property.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a fast fail in your action handler

```
handleChange(e) {
    const requiredValues = [3, 5]
    if (!requiredValues.includes(e.target.value) return
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is how I'd do it!

Answer (score 0):

underscore provides a method called [`_.after()`](http://underscorejs.org/#after). This might suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your "select" handler logic after you have multiple values.

One example would be storing the selected values in state and the handler would look like this :

```
onChangeHandler = (e) => {
  this.setState({ values } => {
    const newValues = values;
    const currentValue = e.target.value;

    const index = values.indexOf(currentValue);

    if (index > -1) {
      // Remove value
      newValues.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      // Add value
      newValues.push(currentValue);
    }

    // You can do your logic here, before state is updated
    // if (newValues.length > 1) {
    // do multiple values logic
    // }

    // Update state
    return {
      values: newValues
    }
  }, () => {
    // You can do your logic here, after state is updated
    // if (this.state.values.length > 1) {
    // do multiple values logic
    // }
  })
}
```