# Flask WTF forms: can a new field be shown if a user selects a specific choice in SelectMultipleField?

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I just started using Flask WTF forms.  I can do everything that I need with them except I can't seem to figure out one thing.  I have a multiple choice field presenting various options to the user, and if the user selects "other", I want them to describe what they mean.  Like this:

```
 impact = wtforms.SelectMultipleField('What is the expected impact?',
                           choices=[('Sales', 'Sales'),
                                    ('Lift', 'Lift'),
                                    ('Other', 'Other')]
```

I don't know if it's even possible when it's not an independent field with its own ID but just a member within an array.   Could you please help?

**EDIT**

here's what I tried following the suggestion below - it didn't work in the sense that selecting or unselecting "Other" makes no difference  :

app.py:

```
app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
     form = MyForm()
     other_enable = False

       if form.validate_on_submit():

          name = form.name.data
          email = form.email.data
          impact1 = form.impact.data
          impact = ''.join(str(e) for e in impact1)

          if ("Other" in impact):
              other_enable = True
          impact_other = form.impact_other.data
          return redirect(url_for('home'))
       return(render_template('home.html', form=form, other_enable=other_enable))
```

and templates/home.html contains

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% import "bootstrap/wtf.html" as wtf %}

<center>

  <div id="someid" onchange='myFunction(other_enable)'>{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}</div>

</center>

{% endblock %}

<script>
     function myFunction(other_enable) {
         var theother = document.getElementById("otherField");

         if (other_enable == true){
            theother.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            theother.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add another field in your form like `TextField()` and make it `validator.Optional()`.

Then with simple javascript and `onchange` event you can `display:none` this field by default and if user select `Other` show it.

At the end if you want force user to "describe what they mean" you could add in YourForm class this method :

```
def validate(self):
    """ Add custom validators after default validate
    """
    success = super(YourFormClass, self).validate()

    if 'Other' in self.impact.data and len(self.impact_other.data) < 1:
        success = False
        self.impact.errors.append(gettext('Please fill impact_other field if you had selected "Other"'))

    return success
```

(assuming other field you created is named `impact_other`)

EDIT : I modified slightly my validate() function for working with SelectMultilpleField instead of SelectField

Next, you don't have to pass `other_enable` variable to your template, by default if nothing is selected you should hide `otherField`, so you need to run your js not only onchange but also after page loaded.

You just have to check into your js function if 'Other' is selected in your field `impact`, if yes then show your field. You can look this question for more help at detecting selected values in JS : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box)

Additionally you have to do `form = MyForm(request.form)` to save user input if form validate fail.

Comment: Thanks Calumah, I tried that but it didn't work (see my EDIT above), maybe I am not understanding how to do what you are suggesting correctly?

Comment: @user3490622 I'v updated my answer, hope this will help you