# Flask WTForm: add new field based on previous input

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a form with a `SelectField` and if a specific option in there is selected I want to show a different field where a user can input more options.

So my form class looks like

```py
class QuestionForm(FlaskForm):
    type = SelectField("Question Type")
    options = SelectField("options", validators=[Optional()])
```

Then my `views\questions.py` blueprint renders the form like

```py
def question():
    ...
    form = QuestionCreationForm()
    form.type.choices = [
        (type, type) for type in ["Type 1", "Type 2"]
    ]
    form.options.choices = ["option 1", "option 2"]
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        ...
    else:
        flash_form_errors(form)

    return render_template(
        "question.html",
        form=form,
    )
```

And finally the `html`:

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_title %}Questionnaire{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
...
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('questionnaire.questionnaire') }}">
        <div id="type_selection" class="select is-medium is-expanded" onchange="WHAT HERE?">
              {{ form.type }}
        </div>
        <div id="option_selection" class="select is-medium is-expanded DISPLAY NONE HERE?" onchange="WHAT HERE?">
              {{ form.options }}
        </div>
    </form>
....
{% endblock %}
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        // ??
    }
</script>
```

So my guess is to have an onchange for my `types`form field and check if the selected value is let's say `Type 2` in order to change the rendering of the `options`field to be displayed. However, I wasn`t able to stick together all the parts correctly.

This questions is a potential duplicate, but I cannot comment there and the answer provided was not specific enough the help a newby like me. Thanks!
[Flask WTF forms: can a new field be shown if a user selects a specific choice in SelectMultipleField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50511324/flask-wtf-forms-can-a-new-field-be-shown-if-a-user-selects-a-specific-choice-in)

Answer (score 0):

To not make you all fuzzy about the answer on this one. You will need some javascript too. There is pretty straight to the point tutorial on youtube that is no longer than 10 - 15 mins , so search for flask dynamic select field. Hope it will help you out.