# How to get multiple select list data in js?

Tags: javascript

```
<form onsubmit = "return checkForm(this)" method="POST" action = "">
<select name="user[11]">
     <option value='1'>one</option>  
     <option value='2'>two</option> 
</select>

<select name="user[12]">
     <option value='1'>one</option>  
     <option value='2'>two</option> 
</select>

</form>
```

I need to get select box values with keys (which i will use for update user)

im using below function

```
function checkForm(frm){
  var inps = document.getElementsByName('user[]');
  console.log(inps );// but its displaying blank nodelist
}
```

Please give your valueable suggestions

Comment: Could take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a weird tag naming (I do not recommend the use of `[` and `]` in attribute values.) You can solve it by using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which allows you to select elements with CSS selectors.

I have used

```
document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="user["]')
```

The `^=` is a part of the [`6.2. Substring matching attribute selectors`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#attribute-substrings). `[name^="user["]` means "*select where the name attribute begins with "user["*.". This will select elements with `user[1]` but also `user[2]` or `user[2][1]` or `users[hello]` or `users[hello` or `users[hello...`

```js
console.log(document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="user["]'));
```

```html
<form onsubmit = "return checkForm(this)" method="POST" action = "">
<select name="user[11]">
     <option value='1'>one</option>  
     <option value='2'>two</option> 
</select>

<select name="user[12]">
     <option value='1'>one</option>  
     <option value='2'>two</option> 
</select>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` and a wildcard for the name attribute:

```
[name^="user["]
```

This means, find all elements that have a `name` property starting with `user[`.

If you want to get the keys from the name property, map it like so:

```
userArray.map(element => Number(element.name.match(/\d+/)[0]));
```

```js
let userArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name^="user["]'));

let userArrayKeys = userArray.map(element => Number(element.name.match(/\d+/)[0]));

console.log("Matched elements",userArray);

console.log("Their Keys", userArrayKeys);
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" method="POST" action="">
  <select name="user[11]"> <!-- I will get selected -->
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
  </select>

  <select name="user[12]"> <!-- I will get selected -->
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
  </select>
  
  <select name="update[12]"> <!-- I will not get selected -->
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    <option value='2'>two</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

You should give your input fields names that better reflect what data they hold, though.

Comment: Thanks Luca by this i am able to check values can you suggest a way to get keys also.

Comment: @Luca Why we not use getElementsByName()

Comment: @BharatDangar Because getElementsByName, to my knowledge, neither supports substring matching, nor a native method for getting elements that have an array-like name construct

Comment: Yes,Got it.Thanks for reply to my comment.

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to select by below

```
function checkForm(frm){
  var inps1 = document.getElementsByName('user[11]');
  console.log(inps1 );
  var inps2 = document.getElementsByName('user[12]');
  console.log(inps2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Except if the `user` indexes are needed you can skip them like:

```
<select name="user[]">...</select>
<select name="user[]">...</select>

<!-- $_POST values:
    [user] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
    )
-->
```

And then get them as you tried:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByName('user[]'));
// NodeList(2) [select, select]
```