# Add multi select values from drop down list to an Array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to grab selected values from a multi select drop down, and add the selected values to an Array.

The way I currently have it, it adds all of the values in the drop down, rather than the selected values.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="servicePackageTypeText">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <option><?php echo $servicehtml ?></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var sourcetype = document.getElementById("servicePackageTypeText"); 
var servicearray = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < sourcetype.length; i++) 
{ 
    servicearray.push(sourcetype.options[i].value);
}
```

Any tips on how to grab the selected values?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box

Comment: You are right, that post lead me to solving my problem, which I posted below. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using "selectOptions" in my for loop:

```
var sourcetype = document.getElementById("servicePackageTypeText"); 
var servicearray = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < sourcetype.selectedOptions.length; i++) 
{ 
    servicearray.push(sourcetype.selectedOptions[i].value);
}
```