# how to display option in select tag after comma is pressed in input tag

Tags: javascript

I want to display option dynamically after from input text before comma but it is not displaying the option in select tag. For eg if the user types hello and then types comma (,) the value before comma should display on option inside select tag with multiple attributes.

Here is my code:

```js
var skills = document.querySelector('#skills');
var skillhave = document.querySelector('#skill');
var skillshaving = [];

skills.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 188) {

    if (this.value.length < 2) {
      alert("skill required");
      this.value = "";
    } else {
      var skill = this.value.substring(0, this.value.length - 1);
      skillshaving.push(skill);
      this.value = "";
      reloadskills();
    }
  }

});

function reloadskills() {
  skillhave.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < skillshaving.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value += $ {
      skillshaving[i]
    };
    opt.innerHTML += $ {
      skillshaving[i]
    };
    skillhave.appendChild(opt);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter skill" name="skills" id="skills"> <!-- for entering skills via text -->
<select name="" id="skill" multiple></select> <!-- for displaying it in option tag -->
```

Comment: Could you also share the html?

Comment: shared the html too

Comment: I'm not sure what the `$` is doing but I think that instead of doing `+=`, just a simple assignment using `=` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having syntax error while assigning `opt.value` & `opt.innerHTML`. I have updated code as below.

```
opt.value = skillshaving[i]; // Updated code
opt.innerHTML = skillshaving[i]; // Updated code
```

Check output below.

```js
var skills = document.querySelector('#skills');
var skillhave = document.querySelector('#skill');
var skillshaving = [];

skills.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 188) {

    if (this.value.length < 2) {
      alert("skill required");
      this.value = "";
    } else {
      var skill = this.value.substring(0, this.value.length - 1);
      skillshaving.push(skill);
      this.value = "";
      //reloadskills();
      addSkills(skill);
    }
  }
});

//function reloadskills() {
//  skillhave.innerHTML = "";
//  for (var i = 0; i < skillshaving.length; i++) {
// var opt = document.createElement('option');
// opt.value = skillshaving[i]; // Updated code
// opt.innerHTML = skillshaving[i]; // Updated code
// skillhave.appendChild(opt);
//  }
//}

function addSkills(skill) {      
  var opt = document.createElement('option');
  opt.value = skill;
  opt.innerHTML = skill;
  opt.selected = true;
  skillhave.appendChild(opt);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter skill" name="skills" id="skills"> <!--for entering skills via text -->

<select name="" id="skill" multiple></select>
<!--for diplaying it in option tag -->
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but how can we make option selected which are pushed

Comment: I have replaced your `reloadskills` function with `addSkills`. It will add new option as `selected`.

Comment: one more doubt how can i make that minimum of 3 option is selected

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866169/how-to-get-all-selected-values-of-a-multiple-select-box.

Comment: but in this there is no specified condition of minimum option selected

Comment: Yes, but you can try from it and not able to get it done then ask another question.