# How to map only the checked options of a select element

Tags: javascript

I need to map to an array the selected options inside select element (multiple selection is enable).

Here is the html:

```
<select id="listado" size="5" multiple>
    <option value="Leer" id="aficion-leer">Leer</option>
    <option value="Programar" id="aficion-programar">Programar</option>
    <option value="Cine" id="aficion-cine">Cine</option>
    <option value="Deporte" id="aficion-deporte">Deporte</option>
</select>
```

I tried this:
`Array.from(document.querySelector("#listado")).map(elemento => elemento.value);` which returns every option. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31544256/11828396), adding `option:checked` to the query param should do the trick, but I get an empty list.

Any idea on what the reason might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` and only select options that are  checked, then map them.

```js
let options=[...document.querySelectorAll("#listado option:checked")].map(elemento => elemento.value)
console.log(options)
```

```html
<select id="listado" size="5" multiple>
  <option value="Leer" id="aficion-leer">Leer</option>
  <option value="Programar" id="aficion-programar" selected>Programar</option>
  <option value="Cine" id="aficion-cine">Cine</option>
  <option value="Deporte" id="aficion-deporte" selected>Deporte</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What do the triple dots do here? I thought they were used to make copies of objects but I don't see how that'd be useful in this situation, yet it doesn't work without them.

Comment: @LuisFernandez Its called Spread operator read about it here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax Its because `querySelectorAll` returns a list, not array, so you have to put those list items in array in order to map it.

Comment: That' right, but it is more safe to use `Array.from`

Comment: You can use for each without spread operator and then push values from the list: let `options = []
document.querySelectorAll("#listado option:checked").forEach(elemento => options.push(elemento.value))` @LuisFernandez

Comment: @blaumeise20 Hows that?

Comment: Yeah, that's also possible. But I think it is faster and more compatible to old browsers when you use `Array.from`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```js
console.log(
    Array.from(document.querySelector("#listado").childNodes).filter(elemento => elemento.selected).map(elemento => elemento.value) // this line
);
```

```html
<select id="listado" size="5" multiple>
    <option value="Leer" id="aficion-leer">Leer</option>
    <option value="Programar" id="aficion-programar" selected>Programar</option> <!-- selected for demo -->
    <option value="Cine" id="aficion-cine">Cine</option>
    <option value="Deporte" id="aficion-deporte">Deporte</option>
</select>
```