# Populating textarea with selected options

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a select tag with multiple selection. It has about 8 options. I want to make a text area or a place where it will show the options i have selected. Im working on something that will have like 100 options in select tag and i want to keep track of which options i select.
Any ideas how to?
It can be in javascript or jquery.

```js
const ddselect = () => {
  var d = document.getElementById("node-input-options");
  let displayText = d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
  document.getElementById("txtArea").value = displayText[i];
  console.log(displayText);       
};
```

This populates the textarea but with only 1 option.

Comment: You need a data structure in between the <select>s and the <textarea>. When a <select> is changed, the data structure (like an array or object) is changed; then the textarea text is updated based on the data structure.

Comment: How would i implement that in code?

Comment: Do you know how to create an object you can then update and read back later?

Comment: I made an array. In it i push the  selected options. But i have no idea how to populate the textarea with multiple values

Comment: Here's a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/fktq87vn/

Comment: Take a look in my example. I want to have multiple options outputed 1 under another lets say.   Cucpake and gingerbread for example : https://jsfiddle.net/fktq87vn/

Comment: You need to fork the fiddle; you posted mine.

Comment: oops, sorry. https://jsfiddle.net/qaksw7bp/ here it is

Comment: Ok, sounds like you primarily need this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5867262/5734311

Comment: Thank you, but i managed to fix it.