# Angular test .spec.ts How to select multiple options

Tags: angular, angular-test, angular-unit-test

I have a multiple Select list that I want to test, basically when you select n items you then click a button that will copy the items from one list an another. I am having problems trying to select more than one value. This is a multi select so I want to be able to select n items.

I can select one item with this line, but how do I select multiple items in the test?

```
select.value = select.options[0].value;
```

here is the test *selector.component.spec.ts*

```
 it('When assign button is clicked expect to be displayed in assigned list', () => {

    let unassignedItems = [
      { id:1, name: 'Rob' },
      { id:2, name: 'Dave' },
      { id:3, name: 'Steve' }      
    ] as Person[];
    component.unassignedItems = unassignedItems;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    let select: HTMLSelectElement = unassignedItemsSelect.nativeElement;    
    select.value = select.options[0].value;
    select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    assignedItemButton.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    expect(component.assignedItems[0].id).toBe(1)
    
  })
```

The component looks like this *selector.component.ts*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from '../Person';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss']
})
export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  unassignedSelectedItems: Person[] = [];
  assignedSelectedItems: Person[] = [];

  @Input() unassignedItems : Person[] = [];
  @Input() assignedItems: Person[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  assignSelections(): void {
    this.assignedItems.push(...this.unassignedSelectedItems);
    // remove the item from the unassigned list
    this.unassignedSelectedItems.forEach(selectedItem => {
      let index = this.unassignedItems.findIndex(x => x.id == selectedItem.id);
      this.unassignedItems.splice(index, 1); // removes the item at that index  
    });
    // clear the selected item for the next ones
    this.unassignedSelectedItems = [];
  }

  unassignSelections(): void {
    this.unassignedItems.push(...this.assignedSelectedItems);
    // remove the item from the assigned list
    this.assignedSelectedItems.forEach(selectedItem => {
      let index = this.assignedItems.findIndex(x => x.id == selectedItem.id);
      this.assignedItems.splice(index, 1); // removes the item at that index
    });
    // clear the selected item for the next ones
    this.assignedSelectedItems = [];
  }

}
```

The template looks like this *selector.component.html*

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-3">
            <select id="unassignedItems" class="form-select" multiple [(ngModel)]="unassignedSelectedItems">
                <option *ngFor="let item of unassignedItems" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-1 align-middle" >
            <button id="assignedItemButton" [disabled]="unassignedItems.length==0" class="btn btn-primary m-1" type="button" (click)="assignSelections()">&gt;</button>
            <button id="unassignedItemButton" [disabled]="assignedItems.length==0" class="btn btn-primary m-1" type="button" (click)="unassignSelections()">&lt;</button>
        </div>

        <div class="col-3">
            <select id="assignedItems" class="form-select" multiple [(ngModel)]="assignedSelectedItems">
                <option *ngFor="let item of assignedItems" [ngValue]="item">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky one, testing a native multi select. The problem is, that `<select>` doesn't reflect all selected values in it's `value`, only one of them. So setting it to multiple values won't have any effect. Given the awkward way to [extract multiple selected values from a select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31544256/4256274), and the fact that testing native behavior and `ngModel` probably isn't (and shouldn't be) your goal, I'd settle for setting the `unassignedItems` and `assignedItems` manually.

But if you really want to simulate this in your test the "native" way, set the options you want to select like

```
options[0].selected = true;
```

and then emit the `change` event. This will update `<select>`'s `selectedOptions` property, which is used internally by angular's `SelectMultipleControlValueAccessor`. Check its [code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_multiple_control_value_accessor.ts#L143) if you find it interesting. That code will execute upon `change` event, grab the `selectedOptions`' values, and propagate them into the variable associated with `[(ngModel)]`.